# Is this cascading encryption, and is my security weakened as a result?

Tags: encryption, macos

I'm trying to understand what is, and what is not, considered cascading encryption. All of the posts and conversations I've read over the past few days discourage the practice, including [this article](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/02/multiple-encryption.html). Unfortunately, I don't really understand the variables in the equations.

So, I haven't found anything that appears to address the setup, scenarios, and concerns I have in mind.

**What I think I know:**

1. AES is a cipher, and there are no known weaknesses in the cipher.
   GPG is a crypto suite (a.k.a., "the implementation"?), and there are
   no known backdoors or weaknesses
2. OSX Disk Utility is (or could be considered) a crypto suite (a.k.a.,
   "the implementation"?), and I ASSUME there are no known backdoors or
   weaknesses
3. OSX Filevault 2 is (or could be considered) a crypto suite (a.k.a.,
   "the implementation"?), and I ASSUME there are no known backdoors or
   weaknesses Initial

**Assumptions:**

4. No known backdoors or weaknesses in the ciphers or crypto suites
5. AES (at least 128) is used exclusively
6. Each encrypted "thing" (file, disk image, disk) is encrypted with a
   UNIQUE, random passphrase of sufficient length
7. Passphrases will not be leaked (by accident, rubber-hose, etc.)
8. Computer is not currently compromised (no monitoring, keyloggers,
   etc.)

**Questions:**

1. Any single "thing" (file, disk image, disk) 1) encrypted with AES,
   2) via any of the crypto suites above, 3) using a sufficiently long
   and random passphrase, provides "good" security, yes?
2. A GPG-encrypted file exists inside a Disk Utility-encrypted disk
   image. The disk image is not decrypted (not mounted). A copy of the
   disk image is stolen by someone who is equally knowledgeble as you
   in security matters. Is the file less secure inside the disk image
   than if it existed outside the disk image? Is it more secure? Why?
3. A GPG-encrypted file exists inside a Disk Utility-encrypted disk
   image. The disk image is not decrypted (not mounted). The disk image
   exists on an FileVault 2-encrypted disk. The computer is turned off
   and so the disk is not mounted. The computer is stolen by someone
   who is equally knowledgeable as you in security matters. Is the file
   less secure inside the disk image, on that encrypted disk, than if
   it existed outside the disk image and on an unencrypted disk? Is it
   more secure? Why?